# Goal completions 10x higher in dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I have the following table in my Dashboard:

```
Page path level 1    Visits    Goal Completions
-----------------    ------    ----------------
/sub1/               994       1,295
/                    102       3
/sub2/               10        1
```

I know my conversion rate is 10-20%, and that actually in this period I only had 183 goal completions under `/sub1/`.

My goal is set as a regular expression for a particular page (`/success?.*`), and I have a funnel set up which tracks the page before the goal (`/action`).  The actual urls hit would be `/sub1/action` then `/sub1/success?1234` and `/sub2/action` then `/sub2/success?1234`.

Why is my table in my dashboard giving me wildly wrong numbers?  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I believe the Goal Completions you see on the dashboard sum up all te goals you have. Do you have more than 1 Goal configured for this profile?

Comment: I only have 1 goal...